# Azure DevOps - VSBuild for a specific project with publish not working

Tags: web-applications, azure-devops, msbuild, azure-pipelines, publish

I have a solution that has around 63 odd projects however my primary target is around 6 projects. out of which 3 are DotNet Core APIs and 3 Web applications. I was able to publish my DotNet Core APIs using the `DotNetCoreCLI@2` task. Unfortunately, when I try to publish my Web Application, I am facing the following error:

**Error message**

> MSBUILD : error MSB1006: Property is not valid. Switch:
> OutputPath:**\WebApplicationMain\Publish

**YAML**

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '**\WebApplicationMain\MainWebApplication.csproj'
    msbuildArgs: '/t:build /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=publish.pubxml /p:OutputPath:"**\WebApplicationMain\Publish"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

**here's my publish.pubxml**

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Staging</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>False</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>Publish</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

What am I missing here? Any Suggestions?

Comment: you can't use `**` in the path.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk Yeah.. I changed that too /p:OutputPath:"\WebApplicationMain\Publish\" and got an error saying 'MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.'

Comment: try `$(build.sourcesdirectory)\WebApplicationMain\Publish`

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk I am on it :)

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk I got the following error:

MSBUILD : error MSB1006: Property is not valid.
Switch: OutputPath:D:\a\1\s\WebApplicationMain\Publish\

Comment: Oh I found the issue you use `:` instead of `=`, just switch it to `/p:OutputPath="some-path"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `:` in the `/p:OutputPath:` instead of `=`, so just fix it to:

```
/p:OutputPath="some/path"
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks :) I even used the path p:OutputPath=$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebMainPublish\

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the correct answer but it worked for me. I removed the variable $(build.artifactstagingdirectory) and replaced it with a different directory name. I used "stage". I suspect the build agent didn't like the value contained within that variable for that particular project.